# Error in complete.cases(x) : invalid 'type' (builtin) of argument

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I am trying to run a shapiro.test on one variable of my DF.

```
        shapiro.test(chicks.2012)
```

I am getting the following error message

```
  Error in complete.cases(x) : invalid 'type' (builtin) of argument
```

Please note that the variable is a numeric variable and three (3) values are NAs.. 
I would be grateful if someone could explain me what it means.

thank you for any help

Simon

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: if `chicks.2012` is a `data.frame`, what is the variable you want to run the `shapiro.test` on? Or if `chicks.2012` is the variable and `DF` your `data.frame`, have you tried `shapiro.test(DF$chicks.2012)`?

Comment: Thank you,  shapiro.test(DF$chicks.2012) did the trick

Comment: @user2366698 you may want to consider having a look at one of the many R tutorials/introductions to learn about how to work with `data.frame`s (and perhaps other data types as well) in R

Answer (score 1):

`complete.cases()` is used in `shapiro.test()` to get rid of NAs. It should return a logical vector, quite equivalently to `!is.na()`. Given the error you get, I guess `chicks.2012` is not a vector, which it should be.